# calling setTimeout without element ID in Javascript

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have the following code for a fade animation in Javascript:

```
var ticks = 20;
function fadein(tick,element){
    if(element == null)
        return;

    element.style.opacity = tick/ticks;
    if(tick < ticks) {
        var s = "fadein(" + (tick+1) + "," + element + ")";
        setTimeout(s, 500/ticks);
    }
}
```

The problem is this line:

```
var s = "fadein(" + (tick+1) + "," + element + ")";
```

Element is turned into its string representation and causes an error on the next iteration. I know I could do this if all my elements had IDs by passing the eid, but I want to fade in a lot of different things (at different times) and don't want to have to name each one. Is there a way to do this in js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an anonymous function instead of the string to call `setTimeout`. That way you have easy access to all variables inside the `fadein` function.

Besides this it is considered bad practise to use `setTimeout`or `setInterval` with a string parameter.

```
var ticks = 20;
function fadein(tick,element){
    if(element == null)
        return;

    element.style.opacity = tick/ticks;
    if(tick < ticks) {
        setTimeout( function() { fadein( tick+1, element ); }, 500/ticks);
    }
}
```

Comment: `it is considered bad practise to use setTimeout or setInterval with a string parameter`. Why?

Comment: @RobG To cite MDN: "Using this syntax is not recommended for the same reasons as using eval()" with a link to [Don't use eval!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don%27t_use_eval!)

Comment: Cool. Wherever you write the phrase "bad practice" or "best practice" or similar, always explain why.

Answer (score 1):

Use a function instead of a string:

```
var f = function () { fadein(tick+1, element) };
window.setTimeout(f, 500/ticks);
```

This way you can send the element as a parameter without having to turn it into a string representation.

Using a string in the `setTimeout` method was once the only way, but nowadays it's considered better practice to use a function.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass a function instead of your string... pure js

```
setTimeout(function(){.....}, 500/ticks);
```